# Legacy beans in a JavaFX TableView not updating

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

We're integrating JavaFX onto a large legacy code base containing many "original" Java beans, i.e. the type implemented using `java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport`.

JavaFX does not support update of these style of beans, only initial value, as documented in [javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)

> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through
>   support for attempting to call get() or is() (that
>   is, getFirstName() or isFirstName() in the example above). If a method
>   matching this pattern exists, the value returned from this method is
>   wrapped in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper and returned to the TableCell.
>   However, in this situation, this means that the TableCell will not be
>   able to observe the ObservableValue for changes (as is the case in the
>   first approach above).

Upgrading the beans to the property API is not an option as they live in a separate code base which we don't wish to add JavaFX dependencies on as it is still used by legacy Java 6 projects.

My question, how can I get a TableView to update when properties are changed without having to add/remove listeners onto all the individual beans in the table.

I was considering creating my own version of PropertyValueFactory which supports this, but I'd like to know if there are any other possible solutions.

I've produced two examples to illustrate this.

### TableView using old-school beans

```
public class OldBeanTableView extends Application {
    public class OldBean {
        private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_FOO = "foo";
        private int foo = 99;

        public int getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }

        public void setFoo(int foo) {
            int oldValue = this.foo;
            this.foo = foo;
            pcs.firePropertyChange(PROPERTY_NAME_FOO, oldValue, foo);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<OldBean> beans = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        beans.add(new OldBean());

        TableView<OldBean> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<OldBean, Integer> column = new TableColumn<OldBeanTableView.OldBean, Integer>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("foo"));

        tableView.setItems(beans);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        primaryStage.show();
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> beans.get(0).setFoo(beans.get(0).getFoo() + 1), 0,
                1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

### TableView using new beans

```
public class NewBeanTableView extends Application {

    public class NewBean {
        private IntegerProperty fooProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        public int getFoo() {
            return fooProperty.get();
        }

        public void setFoo(int foo) {
            fooProperty.set(foo);
        }

        public IntegerProperty fooProperty() {
            return fooProperty;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ObservableList<NewBean> beans = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        beans.add(new NewBean());

        TableView<NewBean> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<NewBean, Integer> column = new TableColumn<NewBeanTableView.NewBean, Integer>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("foo"));

        tableView.setItems(beans);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        primaryStage.show();
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> beans.get(0).setFoo(beans.get(0).getFoo() + 1), 0,
                1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: fx comes with a wrapper around old-style beans, called something like JavaBeanpropertyAdapter which should help (might need a custom valueFactory, forgot the detail). Unrelated aside: your OldBean violates bean-spec (must fire _after_ internal state is updated)

Comment: Thanks,  ordering is a typo in my example,  real beans do it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrapolating kleopatra's answer to the generic solution.

```
public class LegacyValueFactory<T, F> implements Callback<CellDataFeatures<T, F>, ObservableValue<F>> {
    private String propertyName;
    public LegacyValueFactory(String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<F> call(CellDataFeatures<T, F> param) {
        try {
            return JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create().name(propertyName).bean(param.getValue()).build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
column.setCellValueFactory(new LegacyValueFactory<OldBean, Integer>("foo"));
```

Comment: this is the real solution - mine was just a quick sketch :-) You should accept this.

Answer (score 2):

A very quick example for using JavaBeanProperty as valueFactory:

```
Callback<CellDataFeatures<OldBean, Integer>, ObservableValue<Integer>> valueFactory = cdf -> {
    OldBean bean = cdf.getValue();
    JavaBeanObjectProperty<Integer> wrappee;
    try {
        wrappee = JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create()
                .name("foo").bean(bean).build();

        return wrappee;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
};
column.setCellValueFactory(valueFactory);
```

Note that the bean must have methods add/removePropertyChangeListeners (which your real beans will have anyway :-) to work.

Comment: Many thanks for figuring this out, shame it's not default behaviour, yes, was missing add/remove listeners, I was too quick to post my original question!